# pandas group by and aggregate in a list based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This code groups *X* columns and aggregates *Y* column in one list when the other values are the same. I want to do the same, aggregate into a list but **based in a condition**:

As you can see in the example, from 4 rows I obtain 2 rows, since it's aggregating the *age* column. My condition is that I only want to aggregate them if the bins are next to each other.

In other words: bin [0,20] can only be aggregated with bin [21,40], and bin [21,40] can be aggregated with [0,20] and [41,60], and so on...

I've used the .agg method for that.

Any ideas or suggestions are welcome.

```
# Import pandas library
import pandas as pd

# Create a sample DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'country': ['1', '1', '1', '1'],
    'age': [5, 25, 45, 70],
    'gender': ['M', 'M', 'M', 'M'], 
    'language': ['A', 'B', 'B', 'A']

})

# Define the age bins with custom groups
age_bins = [(0, 20), (21, 40), (41, 60), (61, 100)]
age_labels = ['0-20', '21-40', '41-60', '61-100']

# Define a custom function to group the data based on adjacent age ranges
def custom_age_group(age):
    for i, (start, end) in enumerate(age_bins):
        if age >= start and age <= end:
            return age_labels[i]
    return 'Unknown'

# Apply the custom function to create a new column with the custom age groups
df['age_group'] = df['age'].apply(custom_age_group)

# Group the data based on country, gender, and custom age group
df_out = df.groupby(['gender', 'country','language'])['age_group'].agg(list).reset_index()

# Print the result
print(df_out)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a additional grouping level by extracting the start stop and comparing the start to the previous row's stop per group:

```
cols = ['gender', 'country','language']

bins = df['age_group'].str.split('-', expand=True).astype(int)

g = (df.join(bins)
       .groupby(cols, group_keys=False)
       .apply(lambda g: g[0].ne(g[1].shift().add(1)).cumsum())
     )

out = df.groupby(cols+[g.squeeze()], as_index=False)['age_group'].agg(list)
```

Output:

```
  gender country language       age_group
0      M       1        A          [0-20]
1      M       1        A        [61-100]
2      M       1        B  [21-40, 41-60]
```

Intermediates:

```
bins
    0    1
0   0   20
1  21   40
2  41   60
3  61  100

g
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Works almost good! I spot that when the column "language" is always the same, let's say "A" it throws an error (TypeError: unhashable type: 'DataFrame'
). I'm trying to solve it

Comment: Solved it. Change last line of code to `add cols + [g.squeeze()],  as_index=False)['age_group'].agg(list)`. Can you change it so that I can accept your answer? :) By the way, thank you so much for the help! @mozway

Comment: I updated (you could also have suggested an edit, this gives you a few points) ;)